# About allomorphs of morphemes

Tags: morphology, morphemes

Is it possible for an allomorph of a morpheme to have another allomorph that is a free form? Could you give an example?

Comment: In most theories I'm aware of allomorphs **cannot** have their own allomorphs. It just doesn't make

Answer (score 2):

It is by definition meaningless (contains a false presupposition). A morpheme is an abstraction ranging over a particular set of surface strings having certain properties of form and meaning. An allomorph is one of those concrete contextually determined realizations of a morpheme. Assume a morpheme A which has the realizations {b,c,d,e}. If /A/ is realised as [b] in a context, then it is *not* realized as [c], [d] or [e]. Even if you believe that in some context you first get *b* and then that *b* becomes *c*, [c] is an allomorph of /A/, not of /B/. "Allomorph of allomorph" is a conceptual contradiction.